# Beginner problem with pygame

Tags: python, pygame

I'm just beginning a very simple pygame code that draws a green line on a white background. However, I have to use pygame.display.flip() in order for it to show up, but it seems that I would have to use this every time I made a change and this seems too impractical for me to be doing it right. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a good reason for this.  Double buffering is a technique used to prevent "flickering".  Basically, you want to draw a frame to memory instead of to the monitor and then push the frame all at once when its drawn.  Otherwise, you can see different elements of the same frame go up at different times.

What you want to do is call `pygame.display.flip()` only once per frame draw, not after every change.  Usually, this is done by having a "`draw`" function that is called at the end of a frame once the physics manipulations and game rules are done, and `flip()`ing at the end of `draw`.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you will have to call it each time you want to update screen. By default pygame uses double buffering [Wiki link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_buffering#Double_buffering_in_computer_graphics).